# UI dialog not working in setTimeout using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, settimeout

I would like to trigger a dialog after 10 seconds, and this is pretty simple.. Or so I thought :-)

```
function showPopup() {
    $( "#emailPopup" ).dialog({autoOpen:false});
    //alert('Dialog shown');
}
$( "#emailPopup" ).dialog("open");
$( "#emailPopup" ).dialog("close");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#emailPopup" ).dialog({autoOpen:false});

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        showPopup();
    }, 4000);

    jwplayer('videoBox').setup({
        flashplayer: '<?php echo asset_url(); ?>swf/player.swf',
        file: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oj8CwmP_Jm4',
        height: 329,
        width: 540,
        events:{
            onBeforePlay:function(){
                $('#videoTitle').hide();
                $('#videoReplay').hide();
            },
            onPlay:function(){
                videoStarted = true;
                clearTimeout(popTO);
            },
            onComplete:function(){
                home.flashGetStarted();
                $('#videoReplay').show();
            }
        },
        plugins: 'fbit-1'
    });
});
```

When I run the code showPopup IS run, and I can verify this using debug in [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29), but after calling the dialog, I still don't see any dialog. If I do a straight call to a dialog outside of the setTimeout, it works... But inside, it's a no go.

Comment: Should not be your problem, but should be coded like this: window.setTimeout(showPopup, 4000);

Comment: Is that the exact code? Is it wrapped in any way?

Comment: Why do you just have `modalOptions` there like that?

Comment: Keep in mind that 10 seconds corresponds to 10000 milliseconds...

Comment: Your code of course works as-is without the dialog("show") (you didn't give us the initialization code so we can't test that.). You should be getting some information in your console, most likely telling you that you must first initialize the widget. http://jsfiddle.net/Aykqf/

Comment: Kinsho - yes, you're correct but I was testing with a lower threshhold

Comment: modalOptions were a remnant from some other testing, my apologies for including it

Answer (score 2):

In order to use  `open` method on a dialog you first need to initialize the dialog.

```
$( "#emailPopup" ).dialog({autoOpen:false}); 

function showPopup() {
     $( "#emailPopup" ).dialog("open"); 
     //alert('Dialog shown');
}


window.setTimeout(function(){
    showPopup();
}, 4000);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/QtkBL/

Answer (score 0):

> If I do a straight call to dialog outside of the setTimeout it
>   works... But inside, it's a no go

That's because of a different scope.

Comment: the setTimeout calls the method properly after "X" seconds, so I guess I don't understand why there is an issue since it's all wrapped in $(document).ready